# How can I stop audio from playing from a video file?

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api, flash-builder

This code plays Youtube videos. The file works using Debug or Run buttons in FlashBuilder but has a bug when played from a web server or from the Export Release folder: when the second video runs the audio from the first video keeps playing. How can I unload the first audio?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.SWFLoader;

        private var swfLoader:SWFLoader;
        [Bindable] public var  videoToPlay:String
        public function playVideo(videoNum:int):void
        {
            if(swfLoader)
            {
                swfLoader.autoLoad = false;
                swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
                hg.removeChild(swfLoader);             
                SoundMixer.stopAll();
            }
            var videoAddress:String 
            if(videoNum == 1){
                videoAddress = "m2dg6teC7fg";
            }else{
                videoAddress = "0QRO3gKj3qw";               
            }
            videoToPlay = "https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?v=" + videoAddress;    
            play();
        }               
        public function play():void
        {
            swfLoader = new SWFLoader();
            swfLoader.y = 100;
            swfLoader.load(videoToPlay);       
            hg.addChild(swfLoader);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:HBox id="hg">
    <mx:Button id="button1"  y="50"  label="Button1"  click="playVideo(1)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />
    <mx:Button id="button2"  y="50"  label="Button2"  click="playVideo(2)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />        
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to stop first video/audio on second button click is:

Use following in your code to unload first video from swfloader:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.SWFLoader;

        private var swfLoader:SWFLoader;
        [Bindable] public var  videoToPlay:String
        public function playVideo(videoNum:int):void
        {
            if(swfLoader)
            {
                swfLoader.autoLoad = false;
                swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
//              swfLoader.autoLoad = true; 
                hg.removeElement(swfLoader);             
                SoundMixer.stopAll();
            }
            var videoAddress:String 
            if(videoNum == 1){
            videoAddress = "m2dg6teC7fg";
            }else{
            videoAddress = "0QRO3gKj3qw";               
            }
            videoToPlay = "https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?v=" + videoAddress;    
            play();
        }               
        public function play():void
        {
            swfLoader = new SWFLoader();
            swfLoader.y = 100;
            swfLoader.load(videoToPlay);       
            hg.addElement(swfLoader);
        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


<s:HGroup id="hg">
    <s:Button id="button1"  y="50"  label="Button1"  click="playVideo(1)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />
    <s:Button id="button2"  y="50"  label="Button2"  click="playVideo(2)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />        

</s:HGroup>
```

I have edited code below, which works for your problem(I tested it my side). Try it and let me know it's works?

**Edit:**

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.SWFLoader;

        private var swfLoader:SWFLoader;
        [Bindable] public var  videoToPlay:String
        public function playVideo(videoNum:int):void
        {
            if(swfLoader)
            {
                swfLoader.source = "";
                swfLoader.load(null);
                SoundMixer.stopAll();
            }
            var videoAddress:String 
            if(videoNum == 1){
                videoAddress = "m2dg6teC7fg";
            }else{
                videoAddress = "0QRO3gKj3qw";               
            }
            videoToPlay = "https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?v=" + videoAddress;    
            play();
        }                   
        public function play():void
        {
            swfLoader = new SWFLoader();
            swfLoader.y = 100;
            swfLoader.load(videoToPlay);       
            hg.addChild(swfLoader);
        }

        private function onRemove():void
        {

        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:HBox id="hg">
    <mx:Button id="button1"  y="50"  label="Button1"  click="playVideo(1)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />
    <mx:Button id="button2"  y="50"  label="Button2"  click="playVideo(2)" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" />        
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I added your code to my example (see the code above) but the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks very much-- your code works perfectly in Flex4. My module is part of a much larger project written written in Flex3.5 but your code uses addElement which is not available in Flex 3.5. Is there a way to do this in 3.5?

Comment: You should use addChild instead of addElement.

Comment: I cannot use either removeElement or addElement with Flex 3.5 and have replaced them with addChild and removeChild. When this happens the audio is no longer removed when the second video is played.

Comment: As requested, I have updated the original code so it is the same as yours other than the use of addChild for addElement and removeChild instead of removeElement

Comment: I am using flash player 14.0 and testing in firefox. It works but in chrome it's not working. may be i think it's bug can't resolve.

Comment: Is there a way to open this to the broader community?